# Sum of degree differences for simple graphs

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-optimization, extremal-graph-theory

For a simple graph $G$ on $n$ vertices, let us define

$$\mathcal{I}_{n}(G)=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}|\deg\ x_{i}-\deg\ x_{j}|^{3}.$$

I know that there are many different topological indices defined and studied for graphs. Have You ever seen such that was defined similar as above? Can You provide any references?

I am highly interested in finding $\sup \mathcal{I}_{n}$ over all graphs with $n$ vertices (or at least some tight upper bound). What I have tried myself, was noticing that $\mathcal{I}_{n}$ must be maximized by a threshold graph - these graphs produce degree sequences that are extreme points of he convex hull of all degree sequences. But this didn't lead me too far. I will be glad for any insight.

Comment: Is it obvious that this number is always divisible by four -  for any value of 3?

Comment: The "Albertson index" is a bit similar, see http://www.findstat.org/St001350/

Comment: actually, https://dmtcs.episciences.org/1263 considers your invariant with $3:=1$, which might be helpful.

Comment: Divisibility by $4$ is easy (but tedious) to show by induction on the number of edges.

Comment: How do you get that the maximum occurs for threshold graphs? I'm not doubting it but don't see it so I am just wondering how you would show it.

Comment: This index $\mathcal{I_{n}}$ is a convex function of degree sequence $\mathcal {deg}x_{1},...,\mathcal{deg}x_{n}$.  Call the set of all such graphic sequences $D$. Then we can look on $D^{*}=\mathcal{Con}D$ - a convex hull of $D$. $I_{n}$ must then attain it's maximum on some extreme point of $D^{*}$. It can be shown, that such extreme points of $D^{*}$ are exactly those corresponding to threshold graphs.

Comment: It is proven here: https://books.google.pl/books?id=nWfGo_VX5M8C&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=threshold+sequences&source=bl&ots=a6FWmbXrqF&sig=ACfU3U13UDiqe6AV407evAfzRAA1uR-e3A&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjg7OH1ruXnAhUS-6QKHYaYDGYQ6AEwEXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=difference%20sequences&f=false

Answer (score 4):

I will guess that the optimum occurs for $k$ isolated vertices and a complete graph on the other $n-k$ where $k=\lfloor\frac{n+1}5\rfloor.$ The same count occurs for $k$ vertices of degree $n-1$ and no other edges so the other $n-k$ have degree $k.$

Past that I have these observations:

- A graph $G$ and the complement $\bar G$ give the same value to the sum.
- If the maximum degree in an optimal $G$ is $\Delta$ then any degree $\Delta$ vertex is connected to any other. This is because connecting two such increases some of the $|\deg(x_i)-\deg(x_j)|$ but decreases none.
- Similarly two vertices with the minimum degree are non-adjacent.
- For the type of graph I defined above, the count is $k(n-k)(n-k-1)^3.$ The maximum over  the reals occurs at $$k=\frac{3\,n-\sqrt {4\,{n}^{2}-n+1}-1}5\approx \frac{n}{5}-\frac3{20}.$$

As commented, the exponent of $3$ is relevant. Take the conjectured optimal case of a $K_{4t}$ and $t$ isolated vertices. Deleting one edge reduces $2t$ degree difference from $4t-1$ to $4t-2$ and increases $2(4t-2)$ other differences from $0$ to $1.$ If one is summing the square or cubes of the differences that is worse. But with exponent $1$ that is an improvement.

**NOTE** Based on limited calculations, The same things seem maximal if we replace the exponent of 3 by 2

Comment: I agree, in my opinion this should be a maximizer. But it must somehow depend on power $3$. For $1$ instead of  $3$  we get so called "total irregularity index" and maximizer turns out to be different...

Comment: This conjecture is correct up to 13 vertices.  If the focus on threshold graphs is solid, using the representation of a threshold graph as a binary string (0 for add an isolated vertex, 1 for add a new vertex joined to everything so far) might be the way to go.  I think that the effect of changing 01 to 10 in the string is simple.  But I stopped working on it so feel free ;).

Comment: I don't think that last remark - changing $01$ with $10$ - is true. I have been checking best binary sequences with fixed number of ones and the maximisers are not always $111...000$ or $000...111$.

Comment: @StanTuwim That's interesting. Do you find examples that beat Aaron's records?

Comment: Luckily, I have not.